# Até quando vamos ter que ficar perdendo tempo traduzindo o site para a SE reverter tudo?

Tags: debate, bug, tradução

Não é de hoje que inúmeras partes do site já traduzidas voltam a ficar em inglês, e a comunidade precisa, novamente, traduzir. Basta uma pesquisa na tag [tradução](/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o) para verificar que isso é bem frequente.

Novamente, textos já traduzidos voltaram a ficar em inglês:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Sei que a comunidade, felizmente, em breve irá traduzir, mas até quando vamos ficar perdendo nosso tempo retraduzindo essas coisas, pra SE novamente reverter?

A própria ferramenta de tradução já é pouco intuitiva, exigindo um pouco de trabalho dos colaboradores, mas essas reversões irritam e acabam pondo em terra o trabalho dos tradutores.

Quando a SE vai se pronunciar a respeito? Ou vamos continuar perdendo tempo eternamente com textos e strings já traduzidas, porque ninguém da SE se importa ou dá atenção pra isso?

Answer (score 35):

Desculpem estar a escrever em inglês mas o meu português é... muito mau.

Sou o Gervasio, e sou um programador no Stack Overflow (na equipa do Talent, portanto não trabalhando directamente com o produto de Q&A) mas também estou envolvido no Stack Overflow em español como utilizador regular... portanto quando reparei nas "dores" à volta das traduções, tratámos de construir uma aplicação que nos permite tratar da coisa toda.

Comecei por tentar perceber como o nosso sistema de traduções funciona:

- É basicamente um dicionário de frase em inglês => frase traduzida (considerando plurais)
- Este dicionário está armazenado numa base de dados
- Utilizadores gerem as traduções no Transifex
- O processo de build envia as novas strings que estão no código para o Transifex e apaga as strings que já não estão no código
- O processo de build obtém as traduções da base de dados e adiciona-as aos dlls compilados. Se a tradução não for encontrada no dicionário, a versão inglesa é usada.
- As traduções passam do Transifex para a base de dados só depois de um CM fazer uma importação manual

Isto é importante porque **sempre que um programador muda uma string, o novo valor não é encontrado no dicionário e depois a versão inglesa da string é usada.** Isto não quer dizer que a tradução é revertida, quer dizer que não temos uma tradução para a nova string.

Agora, em teoria, tudo isto faz sentido. Em prática, há um bug no processo de build quando este faz o envio das strings para o Transifex. Por vezes, ele apaga strings que não deveriam ser apagadas.

Depois de ver isso, nós no Stack Overflow em español, achamos que poderíamos resolver estes problemas nós mesmos. Se tivéssemos uma base de dados separada que consideramos "a fonte da verdade," e fizéssemos envios para o Transifex que suplantavam o que quer que fosse que o processo de build do SO faz, poderíamos assegurar que as nossas strings estavam sempre correctas no Transifex... e teríamos mais visibilidade para o que se passa.

Construímo-la, completamente open source, e o seu nome é traducir.win. Podes ver [a publicação onde a anunciámos aqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272). Temos estado a usá-la desde então e tem sido óptimo para nós. [Aqui podem ver um webcast que fizemos com o JuanM em inglês](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbpoWXctN3Y) ([aqui está outro em espanhol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgFqnHVnIbA) se te deres melhor com espanhol).

Dá-nos aprovações em camadas, o histórico de quando as coisas foram alteradas, por quem... deixa-nos marcar strings como urgentes para que os mods possam tratar das traduções finais. A base de dados é aberta para qualquer pessoa consultar ou descarregar... e não têm que criar uma conta para o fazer (basta iniciar sessão com a sua conta do SOes).

Construímo-la de maneira a poder ser utilizada em qualquer site internacional... portanto se a quiserem experimentar (digam-me nos comentários), eu faço uma proposta aqui no SOpt Meta e se a comunidade achar que pode ser útil, trato de a pôr a funcionar.

De qualquer modo, quando uma nova funcionalidade for adicionada ou quando uma string for mudada, ainda terão que ir lá traduzi-la. Tudo o que isto faz, é com que nunca se perca uma tradução e com que haja visibilidade para o que se está a passar. Para nós, isso fez uma diferença enorme (ao ponto de alguns tradutores que já tinha saído do site em frustração terem voltado... e traduzimos o Código de Conduta em menos de 24h).

---

Sorry that I'm writing in English but my Portuguese is... pretty bad.

I'm Gervasio, I'm a developer at Stack Overflow (on the Talent team, so not working directly on our Q&A product) but I'm also involved on Stack Overflow en español as a regular user... so when I noticed the pains around translations, we went ahead and built an app that lets us handle the entire thing.

I started by understanding how our translations engine works:

- It's basically a dictionary of English phrase => translated phrase (accounting for pluralization)
- This dictionary is stored in a database
- Users manage the translations on Transifex
- The build process does a push to Transifex of the new strings that are on the source code and it deletes the strings that are no longer on the source code
- The build process gets the translations from the database and adds them to the compiled dlls. If the translation is not found in the dictionary, the English version is used.
- The translations make it from Transifex to the database only after a CM does a manual import

This is important because **any time a developer changes a string, the new value is not found in the dictionary and then the English version of the string is used**. This doesn't mean the translation is reverted, it means we don't have a translation for the new string.

Now, in theory, this all makes sense. In practice, there's a bug in the build process when it pushes the strings to Transifex. Sometimes, it deletes strings that shouldn't be deleted.

After seeing that, we on the Stack Overflow en español, figured we could actually solve these problems by ourselves. If we had a separate database that we consider the source of truth, and we did pushes to Transifex to override whatever SO's build process does, we could ensure our strings were always right in Transifex... and we'd have more visibility into what's going on.

We built it, completely open source, and its name is traducir.win. You can see [the announcement post here](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272). We've been using it ever since and it's been great for us. [Here you can see a webcast we did with JuanM in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbpoWXctN3Y) ([here's another one in Spanish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgFqnHVnIbA) in case you understand that better).

It gives us tiered approvals, history of when things were changed, by whom... it lets us mark strings as urgent and have mods handle the final translations. The database is open for anybody to query or download... and people don't have to create an account (they just log in with their SOes account).

We built it in a way that lets us use it in any international site... so if you'd like to give this a try (let me know in the comments), I'd do a proposal here on meta SOpt and if people think it could be useful, I'd set it up.

Still, when a new feature is added or a string is changed, people still need to go there and translate it. All this does, is to never lose a translation and to give visibility of what is going on. To us, that made a huge difference (to the point where some translators that left in frustration made it back... and we had the CoC translated in less than 24 hours).

Answer (score 22):

A maneira como vamos resolver isso é usando o traducir.win como Gervasio mencionou acima. Este é o próximo passo e um que Nicolas vai liderar com os mods muito em breve. Nós testámos no SOes com sucesso e nos sentimos confiantes em usá-lo aqui também.

Isso é algo que vocês gostariam de tentar?

*SOja está nos primeiros passos de usá-lo também.

Comment: Com certeza!! Tudo que possa melhorar o processo de tradução é bem vindo!!