# Mensagem de erro em Inglês na página de configuração do perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Há uma mensagem de erro em Inglês na página de configuração do perfil:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ah, agora entendi, é sobre a tradução kkk, então não seria a tag bug.

Comment: @Articuno Não é traduzido. Normalmente, para esses problemas, usamos o tag-bug.

Comment: Relacionada: [Sobre partes do site em inglês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingl%C3%AAs)

Comment: Relacionada: [Até quando vamos ter que ficar perdendo tempo traduzindo o site para a SE reverter tudo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7304/28595)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso foi traduzido com o Google, então sinta-se à vontade para corrigi-lo :)

Esse foi um bug em nosso sistema que afetou essa string específica (ela estava sendo armazenada como uma propriedade estática, o que significa que a lógica da tradução não seria necessária).

Isso foi corrigido em todos os sites internacionais no mesmo dia em que foi relatado.

—-

This was a bug on our system that affected that particular string (it was being stored as a static property, which means that the translation logic wouldn’t kick in for it).

This was fixed on all the international sites the same day that was reported.