# Sinalização de comentários em inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

Ao sinalizar comentários, tanto no SOpt como no Meta SOpt, as opções estão sem tradução.

Sinalização no SOpt:

> [image: sinalização de comentário no SOpt]

Sinalização no Meta SOpt:

> [image: sinalização de comentário no Meta SOpt]

Comment: Quem não saca mt de inglês, é sempre bom recorrer ao velho Google Tradutor. 

Comment: SE ataca novamente!!

Comment: Relacionada: [Até quando vamos ter que ficar perdendo tempo traduzindo o site para a SE reverter tudo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7304/28595)