# Texto de edição de pergunta em Inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro em Inglês

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem um motivo para isso acontecer ?

Comment: Defina normal :D

Comment: "Normal" não sei, mas anda sendo "comum".

Comment: O SOpt não deveria ser todo em pt-BR ? tem uma explicação para algumas partes do site estar em inglês ?

Comment: Eu diria que um dos sites mais visitados do mundo, e um dos maiores sobre programação, não ter uma solução decente para internacionalização, realmente é algo que não tem explicação: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7304/112052 :-(

Comment: @Samuel O site muda o tempo todo, e eles não traduzem as mudanças. Sobra para a comunidade traduzir quando dá.

Comment: @hkotsubo pense no lado bom, pelo menos sobram o chat, a pesquisa e os filtros contra abuso de sistema, que são ótimos!    /s

Comment: @bfavaretto trágico mas uma realidade, certamente quem pode ajudar com tradução é quem tem uma pontuação alta no site.

Comment: Encontrei aqui no meta - [Mil tradutores são melhores que um](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2705/mil-tradutores-s%c3%a3o-melhores-que-um)

Comment: O post é de 2015, quem quiser colaborar com traduções ainda deve usar o Transifex?

Comment: @RafaelTavares Agora é feito no https://pt.traducir.win/ - Samuel, qualquer um pode ajudar nas traduções, independente de ter pontuação alta ou não