# A mensagem de aprovação de edição está em inglês

Tags: bug, internacionalização, idioma

A mensagem que informa que sua edição está pendente para aprovação ainda está em inglês:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A maioria das traduções são feitas pelo Traducir ([veja mais detalhes aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7518/100416)). Qualquer membro pode fazer uma sugestão, e [alguns podem revisar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8597/100416). O maior problema é que de vez em quando o SO atualiza algumas coisas e "apaga" várias traduções.

Comment: Inclusive, é duplicata dessa [Texto de edição de pergunta em Inglês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8347/texto-de-edi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-pergunta-em-ingl%c3%aas) (sem resposta)